# Base 10 to 2 generating function?

Tags: generating-functions, binary

I’m working in Desmos on a larger project that involves base conversion. I managed to come up with this function that gets the job done but I’m wondering if there’s a simpler way to do things (in a form I can write out in Desmos), or if this is the simplest way. Thanks.

$$C(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \log_2x \rfloor} 10^n \cdot \left(\Big\lfloor \frac {x}{2^n} \Big\rfloor \bmod2\right)$$

Comment: So for example $C(3)=11$?

Comment: I don't see any [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) here

Comment: It seems to me this is more of a "base $2$ to base $10$ reinterpretation" function, that is, it takes a numeric value, makes the base-$2$ representation of that value (consisting of a string of $1$s and $0$s), and produces the value of that string of digits interpreted in base $10$. But to perform actual base conversion I think you need to be dealing explicitly with strings of digits, not numerical values (which have no inherent "base").

Comment: To clarify: base conversion means you represent the same number with different strings of digits. What you have here is two different numbers that are represented by the same string of digits.

Comment: quite right. That is what I meant, sorry.